# Find string in table VBA Powerpoint

Tags: vba, cell, powerpoint

After 2 days trying to find a solution to my problem, I need your help please.
I'm working on powerpoint VBA script, and I've got a Table (3,3). In the row 1, I've already input some string in cells.

I want to know why my script doesn't want to write NOK in cells when the string does'nt match "comp" for example

Here is my VBA script:

```
Public Sub CreateTable1()
' déclaration of variables
Dim objSld As Slide
Dim objShp As Shape
Dim foundText1 As Object
Dim FindWhat As String
Dim I As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Set objSld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
Set objShp = objSld.Shapes.AddTable(3, 3, 15, 150, 700, 500)

' Give a name to table
objShp.Name = "Table1"

' Define size of cells
With objSld.Shapes("Table1").Table
    .Columns(1).Width = 115
    .Columns(2).Width = 115
    .Columns(3).Width = 115
    .Rows(1).Height = 120
    .Rows(2).Height = 120
    .Rows(3).Height = 120

    'Write in cells
    With .Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame
        .TextRange.Text = "Composition"
    End With
    With .Cell(2, 1).Shape.TextFrame
        .TextRange.Text = "Material"
    End With
    With .Cell(3, 1).Shape.TextFrame
        .TextRange.Text = "Method"
    End With

' Define text position
    For I = 1 To 3
        For j = 1 To 3
            With .Cell(j, I).Shape.TextFrame
                .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
                .HorizontalAnchor = msoAnchorCenter
                .TextRange.Font.Size = 18
            End With
        Next j
    Next I

'Command find
'Browse row 1 from line 1 to 3
For x = 1 To 3
    Set foundText1 = objSld.Shapes("Table1").Table.Cell(x, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Find(FindWhat:="Comp")
    If foundText1 = "Comp" Then
        'MsgBox foundText1 & x
        'Will write in cell (x,2) OK and x
        objSld.Shapes("Table1").Table.Cell(x, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "OK " & x
    Else
   'Will write in cell (x,2) NOK and x
    'Doesn't works !! Why??
        objSld.Shapes("Table1").Table.Cell(x, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "NOK " & x
    End If
Next x
End With
End Sub
```

I Would like to know if you see where is the mistake. The function Else seems not working..

Comment: foundText1 returns a TextRange object, so you should be checking if the object is nothing or not prior to checking against the text value.

Comment: Thanks for this quick reply but I tried it already with the function : 
    - Do While Not (foundText1 Is Nothing)
    - Loop 
But my application crashed ..

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution !!

For those who're lost with this same problem, here is my code:

```
Public Sub CreateTable1()
' déclaration of variables
Dim objSld As Slide
Dim objShp As Shape
Dim foundText1 As Object
Dim TextRng As TextRange
Dim FindWhat As String
Dim I As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Set objSld = ActivePresentation.Slides(8)
Set objShp = objSld.Shapes.AddTable(3, 3, 15, 150, 700, 500)

' Give a name to table
 objShp.Name = "Table1"

' Define size of cells
With objSld.Shapes("Table1").Table
    .Columns(1).Width = 115
    .Columns(2).Width = 115
    .Columns(3).Width = 115
    .Rows(1).Height = 120
    .Rows(2).Height = 120
    .Rows(3).Height = 120

    'Write in cells
    With .Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame
        .TextRange.Text = "Composition"
    End With
    With .Cell(2, 1).Shape.TextFrame
        .TextRange.Text = "Material"
    End With
    With .Cell(3, 1).Shape.TextFrame
        .TextRange.Text = "Method"
    End With

' Define text position
    For I = 1 To 3
        For j = 1 To 3
            With .Cell(j, I).Shape.TextFrame
                .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
                .HorizontalAnchor = msoAnchorCenter
                .TextRange.Font.Size = 18
            End With
        Next j
    Next I

'Command find
'Browse row 1 from line 1 to 3
End With
End Sub
```

Creation of a second sub to understand where does script failed
    Sub yolo()

```
Dim objSld As Slide
Dim oTbl As Table
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim foundText1 As Object
Set objSld = ActivePresentation.Slides(8)

Set oTbl = objSld.Shapes("Table1").Table
With oTbl

    For lRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
            With .Cell(lRow, 1).Shape

               'Do something with each cell's text
               'Does this shape has text?
                If .HasTextFrame Then
                    Set TextRng = oTbl.Cell(lRow, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange
                        Set foundText1 = TextRng.Find(FindWhat:="Comp")
                        Do While Not (foundText1 Is Nothing)
                            With foundText1
                                oTbl.Cell(lRow, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "OK"
                                Set foundText1 = TextRng.Find(FindWhat:="Comp", After:=.Start + .Length - 1)
                            End With
                        Loop
                End If
            End With
        Next lRow
End With

End Sub
```